# Ant- 'Java' target failed: can not find or load main-class

Tags: java, ant

Given such `Ant` script, it runs the `main` class in SparkTest.

```
<target name="makeQuery" depends="makeJar">
    <java classname="sparkDemo.SparkTest" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/SparkDemo.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

I got such error:

```
makeQuery:
 [java] Error: Could not find or load main class sparkDemo.SparkTest
```

What's the issue? The `SparkDemo.jar` have dependency on several other jar files, then how to set the dependency in `Java` target?

Comment: the jar file is there, with the class in it? if it has dependency you ll get stack trace saying that the dependency is not found

Comment: But that error is the only error I got from the command line

Comment: see if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean , you need to give us more details